# If statement depending on function results

Tags: python, validation, if-statement

I have created a function named validate which checks if a sequence is DNA, RNA or something else. If it is DNA or RNA it prints a message that it is valid, otherwise that it's invalid (`seqtype` is what I have named the type of biological sequence based on which the validation is done):

```
def validate (self):                                       
    if self.seqtype == "DNA" or self.seqtype == "RNA":                                     
        self.seqtype == self.seqtype                                    
        print ("The sequence is valid")                        
    else:
        print ("The sequence is invalid")
```

Now the user has to input a sequence. This input must be "passed" through the function validate and if the input is valid, add the input to a table, otherwise if it is invalid, print an error statement. In other words something like this:

```
if The sequence is valid:
    CONTINUE TO THE NEXT TASK 
elif The sequence is invalid:
    PRINT AN ERROR MESSAGE TO THE USER
```

Can you please help me how to do that?

Comment: Your entire validate function could simply read: `return self.seqtype in ["DNA", "RNA"]` which would return True or False, allowing the caller to print results as needed and/or execute the next task.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could want to make `validate()` function a static class method by using the built-in [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) function as a decorator. Doing so will allow you to call it whenever needed, even before an instance of the class has been created.

Below is an example of doing what I am suggesting:

```
class Nucleotide:
    def __init__(self, seqtype):
        self.seqtype = seqtype

    @staticmethod
    def validate(seqtype):
        return seqtype in {"DNA", "RNA"}

    def next_task(self):
        print('...performing next task.')


while True:
    seqtype = input('Enter sequence type: ("DNA" or "RNA"): ')
    if not Nucleotide.validate(seqtype):
        print("Sorry, that sequence type is invalid, please try again.")
    else:
        print("That sequence is valid.")
        molecule = Nucleotide(seqtype)
        break  # Get out of loop.

molecule.next_task()  # Perform next task.
...
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response!
I think what i have to do is make validate function return a boolean value and depending on the true/false result continue with the next steps. Any ideas how to do that?
I forgot to mention that both the validation function as well as the next process i have to do must be in the same class

Comment: Where does the call to the validation function (and potentially the next processing) take place?

Comment: The class and the validation function must be in a python program.
Then i have to write a new program that imports the class, uses the validation function to validate a biological sequence that the user inputs. If the validation is True the new program must add the biological sequence to a MySQL table (that i already have created in another step), otherwise show an error message to the use

Answer (score 0):

```
def validate (self):                                       
    if self.seqtype == "DNA" or self.seqtype == "RNA":                                     
        self.seqtype == self.seqtype                                    
        print ("The sequence is valid")
        self.next_task() #added, as question says that should do this here                        
    else:
        print ("The sequence is invalid")
```

or add to list, which the question says more specifically, here in but could be in the next_task or some add_valid method.

```
def validate (self):                                       
    if self.seqtype == "DNA" or self.seqtype == "RNA":                                     
        self.seqtype == self.seqtype                                    
        print ("The sequence is valid")
        valid_seqs.append(self) #the list must be inited somewhere                
    else:
        print ("The sequence is invalid")
```